# modularization of code

Tags: visualforce-component

The requirement is to reduce the number of lines of code and deconstruct into smaller supporting methods.Can someone help me out in this regard.This method is basically validating different fields on a form and returning them back to a VF component.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably stick to the many tests in the main method but move any repeated logic into separate methods e.g.:

```
private Boolean isRequired(String field) {
    return String.IsNotBlank(requiredFields) && requiredFields.containsIgnoreCase(field);
}
```

I would also get rid of the `isValidationErrorExist` code that is repeated (and as it includes `&& false` looks wrong anyway) and just assign it at the end if its needed:

```
isValidationErrorExist = emailError || storeLocationError || ... ;
```